# Visual studio 2008 variable suggestion

Tags: c++

I ve been told there is a tool that makes visual studio suggest variables, just like in the xcode.
If we have int integerX,
then when we start writting integ, we can press enter or something so the variable will autofill.
help?

Comment: I don't use the IDE, but I think it's [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't just comment yet...

If you press `Ctrl + Space` after you typed a variable first (what you did, according to your question), it will pop up the variable(s) too. As the first hit.